# Create a Picturebox when a button was press

Tags: vb.net, operating-system, icons, controls, desktop

I am creating an OS system called KernalOS With full functioning desktop But my problem is I want to be able to add an Icon when I click a button. I want the Icon to detect if mouse button was down / clicked.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim newPictureBox As New PictureBox
    newPictureBox.Visible = True
    newPictureBox.Top = 20
    newPictureBox.Width = 100
    newPictureBox.Height = 50
    newPictureBox.Left = 10
    'add control to form
    Controls.Add(newPictureBox)
    newPictureBox.Location = New Point(100, 100)
End Sub
```

This code isn't working right so Idk what going on or why its not working. Please ask question I will fill you in with details. thanks Guys

Comment: Please define _"isn't working right"_. What is/isn't happening? If the problem is simply that you don't see any new picture box, perhaps you should add an image to it or change its back color? It usually inherits the back color from the parent, which in that case makes it "invisible".

Comment: Also, you are currently changing its location twice. The `Top` and `Left` properties are the same as the X and Y you pass to `New Point(100, 100)`. So you only need to change either `Top` _**and**_ `Left`, or **only** the `Location` property.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `AddHandler` Event:

```
newPictureBox.AddHandler, AddressOf newPictureBox_Click

newPictureBox.AddHandler, AddressOf newPictureBox_MouseDown
```

Now I'm not sure about how precise that is; you now have to write a

```
Private Sub newPictureBox_Click.
```

This is probably not the entire correct syntax, but you get the idea.

Comment: The `PictureBox` class does not have a method called `AddHandler`.  Perhaps  you are confusing it with the `Addhandler` VB statement?

Comment: @Chris Dunaway - Hmmmm. Well I did try it before using a label, not a picturebox. But I did say, >That is not the entire correct syntax.

Comment: `Label` doesn't have an `AddHandler` method either.  Perhaps someone wrote an extension method for it?

Comment: @Chris Dunaway - No. I tried that before. You are wrong.